# What table will be taken if table alias is not provided?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am analyzing one SQL statement and there is something with regard to aliases what isn't really clear to me, so I would like to ask if someone can try to explain it. So, this is how the statement looks like

```
SELECT 
    a.RecordID
    , a.Account
    , b.RecordID
    , c.SomeField as AlternativeFieldName
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.RecordID=b.RecordID
LEFT JOIN TableC c
    ON b.RecordID=c.RecordID
WHERE a.DayFrom >= YYYYMMDD and a.DayFrom < YYYYMMDD
    AND b.Field1 is null
    AND Field2 = 'SOME_VALUE'
```

as you can see aliases are provided for all three tables in the statement and used always in data selection as well as joins, however in the where clause there is one field from one of the tables above for which an alias is not provided. I wonder it this is correct and if it is what does SQL take as a source table or does it throw an error if it is not?

On this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_table), I've tried something similar and it actually worked, although I've expected some error. I thought that SQL forces you to used aliases if joining multiple tables. Here is the statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o 
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE OrderDate = '1996-07-04'
```

Thx in advance, cheers!

Comment: If column name is ambiguous you will get an error. If not query will work.

Comment: if OrderDate is only found in one table than there is no ambiguouty and query will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SQL Server (or any database) finds an unqualified column name, then it looks to see which tables/subqueries in the `FROM` clause or outer queries might be providing it.

If the column is in exactly one table/subquery in the `FROM` clause, then the column is assumed to come from the table/subquery.

If the column is in multiple tables/subqueries in the `FROM` clause, then the query returns an error.

If the column does not exist in the `FROM` clause nor in any outer queries, the query returns an error.

If the column does not exist in the `FROM` clause, but does in an outer query, then that reference is used.

These rules go by the name "scoping".  That is a common term in computer languages for figuring out the value of a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! Although I like the answer from @Dan Guzman too, this one deserves to be accepted!

Answer (score 2):

No error will be raised for unqualified column names as long as the column name is not ambiguous. In the case of ambiguous names, the column name must be qualified with the table name or alias to avoid an error.

Note there is also the notion of scope that can become an issue when column names are not qualified.  Consider this construct:

```
WHERE b.Field3 IN(
   SELECT Field4
   FROM TableD
   )
```

If `Field4` exists in `TableD`, the desired results will be returned. But if Field4 does not exist in `TableD` but exists in one of the outer tables, the predicate will be true for all outer rows when the `Field4` value is not NULL and at least one row exists in `TableD`.

In short, the best practice is to qualify column names in multi-table queries.

Answer (score 0):

Any RDBMS executing the sql queries with joins will try to find column names from all referenced tables. If it finds only one column with that name simply executes the query otherwise throughs ambiguity error. Alias names will be used to avoid ambiguity.